# 99th derivative of Arsh(x) at point 0

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Problem:$$\frac{\mathrm d^{99}}{\mathrm dx^{99}}Arsh(x)$$
Without: Taylor
My attempt:
$$y=Arsh(x)$$
$$y'=\frac{1}{1+x^2}=(1+x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=t$$
$$y''=\frac{-x}{(1+x^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}}=\frac{-x*t}{(1+x^2)}$$
$$-x*y'=y''*(1+x^2)$$ 
And if I use general Leibniz rule on that with n=98 but I can't get just 100st
derivative of y(x).

Comment: It is an odd function.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the *Taylor expansion* of $\DeclareMathOperator\ash{Argsh}\ash x$:
$$\ash x=x-\frac12\frac{x^3}3+\frac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot4}\frac{x^5}{5}-\dots+(-1)^n\frac{1\cdot 3\dotsm (2n-1)}{2\cdot4\dotsm 2n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}+\dotsm$$
Comparing with the general Taylor formula yields immediately
$$f^{(n)}(0)=(-1)^n\bigl(1\cdot 3\dotsm (2n-1)\bigr)^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\dfrac{2i}{x^2+1}=\dfrac{x+i-(x-i)}{(x+i)(x-i)}=\dfrac1{x-i}-\dfrac1{x+i}$$

Using [this](http://learnmathforfree.jimdo.com/calculus/nth-derivative/) $r$th derivative of $(x+a)^{-1}$ will be $$(-1)^r\dfrac{r!}{(x+a)^{r+1}}$$

Finally, choose $x=R\cos\phi,1=R\sin\phi$ where $R,\phi$ are real and use De Moivre's Theorem

Here $r=99$